How to handle 401 (Unauthorized) error with Spring Boot backend, React frontend and Keycloak as a resource server?
I am trying to fetch my API (Spring Boot) in React. I am trying to get the name of the logged in user and display it on the frontend.
Dashboard.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { httpClient } from '../HttpClient';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

import '../stylesheets/Dashboard.css';
import Button from "../components/Button"

let initOptions = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8081/',
  realm: 'BlacklightsRealm',
  clientId: 'client1',
}

let kc = new Keycloak(initOptions);

kc.init({
  onLoad: 'login-required',
  checkLoginIframe: true,
  pkceMethod: 'S256'
})
.then((auth) => {
  if (!auth) {
    window.location.reload();
  } else {

    httpClient.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${kc.token}`;

    kc.onTokenExpired = () => {
      console.log('token expired')
    }
  }
}, () => {
  console.error("Authentication Failed");
});

const Dashboard = () => {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo();
  }, []);

  const getUserInfo = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/info', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${kc.token}`
      }
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.name);
        setName(data.name);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching user info:', error));
  };

  const [infoMessage, setInfoMessage] = useState('');

  const logout = () => {
    kc.logout({ redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/' });
    setInfoMessage('Logging out...');
  }

  return (
    <>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="header">Welcome, {name}!</div>
            <div className="content"><h3>{infoMessage}</h3></div>
            <div className="footer">
              <Button onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
    </>
  );
}


export default Dashboard;

HomeController.java
package com.blacklight.cloudgallery.controllers;

import com.blacklight.cloudgallery.services.UserService;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal;
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.security.Principal;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public HomeController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/info")
    public ResponseEntity<UserInfo> getUserInfo(Principal principal) {
        KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext> keycloakPrincipal =              (KeycloakPrincipal<KeycloakSecurityContext>) principal;
        AccessToken accessToken = keycloakPrincipal.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getToken();
        String name = accessToken.getName();
        UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(name);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userInfo);
    }


    public class UserInfo {
        private String name;

        public UserInfo(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

}


SecurityConfig.java
package com.blacklight.cloudgallery.config;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig  {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    //auth.requestMatchers("/images").hasAuthority("SCOPE_admin");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                        .jwt(withDefaults())
                )
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
                //.oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                //.formLogin(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}


enter image description here
I tried to find some blockades in my Keycloak configuration but didn't find anything. I expect that the name is displayed. I already handled CORS-error with the 'CorsConfigurationSource'. I really don't know how to solve the problem. Please tell me if you need more details.
Thank you.

You should read this article I wrote: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2
